# How to develop mult tenancy/clients codeigniter application

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I would like to develop a certain school application by using Codeigniter which will be used by more than one school/client.

Features:

1. Single base code
2. DB for each client (school) and default DB for storing default configs
3. To be able to add client(school) through GUI
4. Single domain/different domains(subdomains)

Any help with example will be highly appreciated.

[My first app Diagram is Attached...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlNSh.png)

Comment: You don't need different DB's for different clients. In fact, doing so makes it not multi tenant at all. Instead, within each table you need to have a check to determine which data belongs to which of your clients. For instance a suppliers table `supplier_id, client_id, supplier_name`.

Comment: Thank you for your response; but some programmers suggest multi DB for the purpose of security, backups and performance. But from your single DB perspective how could I achieve my goal in Codeigniter? thanks